# save password once and use it from different terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, passwords

I have script that runs remote login using SSH, copies a file from that remote machine using SCP without asking for a password, however, the change only works for the terminal where I am running the script.  If I try to execute this same script on a different terminal, it will prompt me for a password.

Is there a way I can create a script that will prompt for my password once, then not ask for my password the next time the script is run?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ssh-copy-id [user@]machine` command to install your public key in the remote machine's authorized_keys.

Answer (score 0):

ssh is rather paranoid of its passwords. You can use its drop-in replacement from putty, it allows to load password from file or even command-line.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a *master* SSH connection that accepts *multiplexing* connections. See the options `-M` and `-S` of the SSH client manual.